# Value cannot pass to controller from angular 8

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

I am using angular 8 with .NET Core 3 and there is issue when I pass parameter of arraylist from angular to .NET Service. the code of delete and get works fine. but facing the issue in arraylist code in case of put I got the ID from angular but didn't get arraylist in other application I use same code and its working fine but for .NET Core 2.0 its .net core 3.1

Here is my .NET code

```
[Route("api/Medicine")]
    public class MedicineController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IDataRepository<Medicine> _dataRepository;

        public MedicineController(IDataRepository<Medicine> dataRepository)
        {
            _dataRepository = dataRepository;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Medicine[] medicine)
        {
            if (medicine == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Medicine is null.");
            }

            _dataRepository.Add(medicine[0]);
            return CreatedAtRoute(
                  "Get",
                  new { Id = medicine[0].MedicineId },
                  medicine);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Put(long id, [FromBody] Medicine[] medicine)
        {
            if (medicine == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Medicine is null.");
            }

            Medicine medicineToUpdate = _dataRepository.Get(id);
            if (medicineToUpdate == null)
            {
                return NotFound("The Medicine record couldn't be found.");
            }

            _dataRepository.Update(medicineToUpdate, medicine[0]);
            return NoContent();
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class Medicine
    {
        public int MedicineId { get; set; }
        public string MedicineName { get; set; }
        public decimal PurchaseAmount { get; set; }
        public int QuantityPurchased { get; set; }
        public int QuantityAvailable { get; set; }

    }
```

i this code delete and get is working fine but arraylist is null
here is my angular service code

```
saveMedicine(Name, price, qty) {
    this.medicine = [];
    this.medicine.push({
      medicineId: 0,
      medicineName: Name,
      purchaseAmount: price,
      quantityPurchased: qty,
      quantityAvailable: qty
    });
    this.http
      .put(
        `${this.bUrl}/Medicine/` + localStorage.getItem("medID"),
        this.medicine
      )
      .subscribe(
        result => this.router.navigate(["/medicine-list"]),
        err => console.error(err)
      );
    // console.log(obj);
  }
```

and Model

```
export interface Medicine {
  medicineId: number;
  medicineName: string;
  purchaseAmount: number;
  quantityPurchased: number;
  quantityAvailable: number;
}
```

Comment: Is there any binding error in your event viewer?

Comment: I got following error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

Comment: @SheikhSaad Does it even hit the `PUT` Endpoint ? Are you getting medicine is null message back?

Comment: In your network tab in the browser, do you see your message `Medicine is null.`? It should be the payload of your 400 error.

Comment: yes its value is null as mention above that i didn't get value in case of put i got ID from front end but no value(Null) of array-list

Comment: one more thing this issue in .net core 3.0 in 2.0 this issue not exists and reason is app.UseEndpoints but i cant resolve this.